# The Ask Question Button is too big

Tags: feature-request, design

See [Jeff Atwood's comment regarding a proposed design with a big "ask question" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69063/help-us-redesign-the-stack-overflow-homepage#comment166186_69088).

> ask question should never be featured, because the easiest way to poison a Q&A community is to enable a flood of bad/sloppy questions.

Given how big the `Ask Question` button is, it will probably encourage a lot of low quality questions - especially since the other links, such as the `Unanswered Link`, are small by comparison.

Comment: I think that applies to Stack Overflow only, for now at least. SO gets 1ks of questions a day, that's why its Ask Question isn't emphasized. For other SE sites, this isn't really the case. In fact, I think the Ask Question should stand out a bit more. At the current rate of new questions, I don't think low quality questions flooding is an issue yet.